# How to free space in lvm pool?

Tags: centos, lvm, pool

I have a newly built CEntOS 7 server with a single large lvm pool we plan to use for VM installations. When I tried to create a new VM instance using ssm, I got errors saying there's no space. So I looked and sure enough the pool is showing 0 free space. How to I open up this space?

[ssm list & df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jN6nz.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

No more free space on the volume group for guest logical volumes.

Note the volume group pools have 0 free. `/dev/vg_tvchost4/root`  mounted at `/` is 5.57 TB, most of the space of disk `/dev/sda`.  Reducing a volume is often tricky, and in this case XFS cannot be reduced.

Backup data. Reinstall the OS, delete these volumes, and change the storage sizing. Consider keeping a VG for OS (`centos`) maybe 200 GB in size containing a modest sized 20 GB `/` plus any swap. Then a data VG (`vg_tvchost4`) with the rest of the storage, but don't create LVs at OS install time.

In general, create storage pools (VG) with all available space at install time, but only create volumes (LV) as needed, with the next year or so of expected capacity. Allows flexibility in creating new volumes (additional guests) or expanding existing.

Comment: This is what I thought I did. created a single storage pool with all available space at install time. But seems I need that "extra" VG to use as the space for the LVs. Let me see if I can figure this out...

Comment: And create / logical volume with a small size, leaving free space. Anaconda automatic partitioning by default will allocate all space in VGs for LVs.